# Is there a way to make MS Outlook print a list of attachments when printing mail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to make MS Outlook print a list of attachments when printing mail? I cannot find the option anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> To work around this problem, change the format of the message to
> either plain text or Rich Text Format before you print the message. To
> change the format of a received message:
>
> Open the message.
> On the Format menu, click either Plain Text or Rich Text.
>
> If the message is in HTML format, you must first click Edit message on the Edit menu.
>
> APPLIES TO
> Microsoft Office Outlook 2003
> Microsoft Outlook 2002 Standard Edition
> Microsoft Exchange 2000 Server Standard Edition
> Microsoft Outlook 2000 Standard Edition

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821840)

And how it appears when printed:

[image]

Comment: In MS Outlook 2000 there doesn't seem to be any Edit/Edit message. Upon changing the format of messages to Rich / Plain text in Options, the list of attachments still stays unprinted. Any advice?

Comment: How strange @Idigas ... I edited my post to use the MS KB article as a reference. It clearly states 2000...